# When to use ultimates in Junkenstein's Revenge?

Tags: overwatch

So the big Halloween update came out, and along with it a new game mode called "Junkenstein's Revenge." My question is, how do I maximize character efficiency, specifically regarding ultimate use?
For example, with Ana I usually give Nano Boost to McCree, so he can use Deadeye on bosses.

Comment: Your title doesn't match what you're actually trying to ask. You might want to expand a bit more as well.

Comment: [Just read this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/574o1w/junkensteins_revenge_a_guide_to_hard_mode/)

Comment: Yeah, usually I prefer Hanzo on the right side. That's basically all I'm doing differently than you. It's because since he doesn't have a hitscan, the fact that the bots spawns a bit closer help him a bit imo.

Comment: The game isn't very complicated and is the same every time, with the same four heroes every time. I don't think there's any reason a comprehensive yet succinct answer couldn't cover this in our format, nor do I expect it to be overly opinion-based. Voted to reopen.

Comment: And it was closed after my answer was already posted and accepted... Sometimes these close votes make next to no sense to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

McCree is the character that will deal the most damage to "Bosses" in a short delay of time, so Ana boosting McCree to deal with bosses faster is a good strategy (Because yes, boosting McCree does increase the charge speed).

Everyone should try to focus as much as possible the grenadier since they are the only mob that will injure you.

### In depth Analysis

---

### McCree

I personally like having McCree top left to keep him safe when bosses spawn and far as much as possible from Roadhog. Since he have a good hitscan, he can deal with bots on the other side of the map. Don't forget to roll with him to reload faster once in a while. And use the flashbang to stop grenadiers for a second or to deal some extra damage to tires.

Make sure you are not the focus target of any boss before launching your ult. Junkrat's bombs (which does a whooping 120 damage on contact) combined with the slowing effect of your ult should lay you down pretty quickly. Roadhog would just hook and take you out of your ult before you can do anything.

Quick heads up, it might be tempting to wait until the very last second to ult because "you'll be able to oneshot them in just a fraction of a second more". Don't. Shoot it, don't be greedy. It happened to me too many times. Your teamates will finish them off. Which wouldn't happen if you didn't shoot at all.

---

### Soldier 76

Soldier 76 is usually in the middle and uses his ult as frequently as he can to clear huge waves of bots. Grenades should be used to deal with grenadiers since it gets rid of 75% of their hp. Since his damage burst is next to inexistant, you should probably defend the gate hp over dealing damage to bosses (except for the grenade who can either deal with grenadier or do a bunch of damage to bosses)

---

### Hanzo

Hanzo likes to be located on a bit higher ground to get good scatter arrows. So 2 good locations would be on the right ledge next to the defender door or on Junkenstein's platform before he spawns. Keep in mind that having him on Junkenstein's platform makes it so no one is really watching the right path. Sonic arrow can be used to show ennemies in blind spots of your team try to use it accordingly. Finally, your ult covers Junkenstein's platform if you launch it on the corner of the tower from the door. Don't be too shy to use it on something else than bosses as it covers an entire path of bots.

---

### Ana

Ana should be able to roam freely with the positionning that I described, this way she can heal everyone easily. Sleep dart should be used to ease the grenadier flow (Sleeping one while the others are being cared of). Sleep dart is also of good use when being used after Reaper's Wraith Form. This way it guarranties McCree's ult to land. Just make sure to land it in the last 3-4 seconds of McCree's channel. Communication with him will ease the process also. Healing grenade is used for both healing and to get rid of tires that gets too near (since you should always be somewhat near the door). And her ult should be used for McCree as said previously or 76 if there's really too much bots coming your way. Shooting enemies with Ana should be only a 1 hit tag (except for grenadier). It makes enemies easier to destroy for your teamates and ensures that you have a good view of the whole battlefield to keep everyone topped off.

Comment: I've noticed from experience that if Mccree is standing on that bridge when Roadhog spawns, he will sometimes go towards you for a hook. You might want to stand back towards the stairs and wait until Roadhog goes towards the door and focuses other players to use Deadeye.

Comment: Thanks forgot to mention it ! I always do this (I'm usually playing McCree)

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of trying to get high scores on the event: **Use ults often.**

Given you have enough enemies to kill, you can build ults again fairly quickly. Even more quickly if you let players who need to build ult do all the killing.

By my estimates:

- Ana takes 40-60 seconds to charge ult
- Mccree takes 15-25 seconds to charge ult
- Soldier takes 25-35 seconds to charge ult
- Hanzo takes 10-30 seconds to charge ult (depends on amount of headshots/misses)

You can use these at about any time as long as you have them for the necessary boss fights. For actual timings:

**Boss Timings**

- 4:41 **Reaper**: Deadeye + Nano Boost
- 2:45 **Roadhog**: Deadeye + Nano Boost, Dragonstrike, Tactical visor
- 1:45 **Junkenstein**: Dragonstrike
- 1:35 **Reaper**: Deadeye + Nano Boost (should clean up junkenstein as well)
- 0:30 **Reaper**: Deadeye (**DO NOT** Nano Boost)
- 0:00 **Triple Threat**:

  - Dragonstrike on as many as you can
  - Deadeye + Nano Boost,
  - Tactical Visor on smaller bosses as necessary, but mainly Roadhog

The shock tires count as Elite kills. I'm not sure if they affect score, but correlationally I've seen ult combos used to kill them leading to higher scores. Anyone's ult will do, but keep in mind the boss timings thereafter.

**Shock tire timings**

- 5:50 **Right**: Anyone

  - Nano boosted Soldier is fun here since there is over a minute before the next boss.
- 5:32 **Left**: Hanzo Dragonstrike

  - Fire from the bottom of the staircase clears many zomnics and the tire. Usually grants POTG.
- 3:53 **Middle**: Soldier or McCree

  - Plenty of time before next boss, but I prefer Soldier. Nano boost can be used here as well.
- 3:38 **Left**: Again, Hanzo Dragonstrike
- 3:22 **Right**: McCree or Solider.

  - McCree preferred for combo-kill potential (though he needs his ult again in about 30s!)
- 2:22 **Right**: Hanzo or McCree.

  - This is right after/during Roadhog, so Soldier usually is on CD. Hanzo or McCree are most likely to have ult again.
- 0:49 **Left + Right**: Hanzo and/or Soldier. Optionally Nano Boost.

  - Hanzo can actually ult from left-to-right and get the right side, while scatter shotting left side tire for easy POTG.
  - McCree should not be used because of the upcoming Reaper fight.

Other than that, all three offensive ults can be spammed at will between bosses. I've found that a large wave of zomnics spawns at every minute mark, so firing a Dragonstrike around then can work wonders.

As long as you don't take door damage or deaths, ult spam/combos can net you a 23-25k score easily.