# How to win junkenstein's revenge in hard

Tags: overwatch

I've been trying for a while now, and never got further than the final battle.

As a Mc cree player, i always get to the ramp, shooting whatever comes, when reaper spawn, i start my ult, ana ults me, and luckily, put him asleep, and even more luckily, no one wakes him up.

But i'm having trouble on the third boss spawn (junkrat then reaper). Since junkrat shoots everywhere, its impossible for Mccre to stand still while ulting, so Ana has to either put junkrat OR reaper asleep.

That putting the risk to waste Mc cree's ult into reaper's wraith...

Who/when should ana use her sleeping dart?
Am I completely wrong?

By the way, I'm putting mostly headshots, the actual problem isn't zomnics, its all about bosses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use ultimates in Junkenstein's Revenge?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288179/when-to-use-ultimates-in-junkensteins-revenge)

Comment: Is more precise than that, its about ana's sleep on bosses

Comment: Which is covered over there too.

Comment: Well, was covered until you edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a **good** 4 man premade is key to win this Brawl in hard. If everyone keeps missing their shots you won't go very far.

Most of the information can be found [there.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/288179/when-to-use-ultimates-in-junkensteins-revenge) But for sake of completing the small elements missing, here's the rest.

Correction to the question : Junkrat isn't "shooting everywhere" he is picking a target. So playing around that should help a lot.

Ana's sleep dart : Junkrat and Reaper are a pain to deal both at the same time. Sleep Reaper in the last 3-4 seconds of the channel time of McCree to ensure the hit. This way McCree will be able to take down both at the same time.

McCree ult : Make sure you are not the focus of any boss when starting it. Your teammates will have to survive until your ult hits.

The final battle should have you destroying the Mercy ASAP. Once she's down, McCree's ult should have taken down Junkrat near to dead (or dead with Hanzo's ult) and Roadhog half HP. From there, if you played somewhat well, your door HP should be high enough to ignore bots (not zombardiers) and take on the bosses.

Comment: Thank, you. One last thing, what would be a good mc cree spot when junkrat spawns? Still top-left (ramp)? Or on the right side, out of junk's sight?

Comment: Same place. Top left. You have all the battlefield in view at this position. You fall back to the door once your ult is done to help the clean up. If you have the opportunity to ult a second time while down there, do it. Cleans up a bit faster ;)

Comment: Reaper isn't in the final fight with Mercy. It's only Mercy, Junkrat and Roadhog.

Comment: I'm just dumb lol. edited.